# js file in custom module's library is not attached when big pipe is running

Tags: javascript

I have a custom module, filter_component, that provides a form. In the form I have:

```
$form['#attached']['library'][] = 'filter_component/filter-component';
```

In filter_component.libraries.yml I have:

```
filter-component:
  version: 1.x
  js:
    js/filter_component.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
    - core/jquery.once
```

filter_component.js begins with:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
    Drupal.behaviors.filterComponent = {
        attach: function (context, settings) {
            $('.block-filter-component', context).once('filterComponent').each(function() {
```

Everything works fine, but only if big_pipe is disabled. When it is enabled, the code is not attached and the js file is not listed in page source or in browser tools as a source.

Comment: Try to remove the .once part.

Comment: The content of the library doesn't matter. If you see the form and not the library then there is something wrong with how the form was rendered, for example too early.

Comment: Yes. What I would like to know is why big pipe is the variable in that happening.

Comment: FWIW I tried adding scope:footer to the js entry in libraries, no difference.

Comment: You don't tell how you render the form.

Comment: It's being rendered via getform() in a block plugin exposed in the custom module.

Comment: If you truly do think this is an issue with big pipe then you should submit an issue in the [big pipe issue queue](https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?version=8.x&component=big_pipe.module) on d.o.

Comment: Yes. But like anything else in the world that needs fixing, often there is a need to find a way around it until it is fixed.

Comment: Indentation of the dependencies should be consistent.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that it was big pipe, but unrelated to my module. Elsewhere on the page a profile image is loaded to appear next to the user name, and if the user has none, a default image. It seems that if a 404 is returned (in this case because part of the oath did not yet exist to match the path supplied for the image), when big pipe goes to load it and gets the 404, downstream js is not loaded.